# How To Remove Specific Nested Array Value From Postgesql JSONB Object

Tags: postgresql

**For mods** I've researched other questions available on SO, however all of them seem overly complex for the issue we're having. My hope is that by asking this question, we'll be able to provide everybody with the most basic/underlying knowledge that they can then build upon the most complex their object becomes.

I'm working in Postgres 15.3, and need help removing `"123456789"` contained within the unsubscribe key array inside of a jsonb object.

Basically this:

```
{
  "spam": [],
  "unsubscribe": ["123456789"]
}
```

To this:

```
{
      "spam": [],
      "unsubscribe": []
}
```

Here is the query I have so far, however at this point

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET columnname = jsonb_set(columnname, '{unsubscribe}', (SELECT jsonb_agg(elem) FROM jsonb_array_elements(columnname->'unsubscribe') AS elem WHERE elem::text <> '"123456789"'))
WHERE primarykey = 'primarykey';
```

This appears to be removing the entire object, rather than just that one instance.

I have also tried

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET columnname = (columnname->'unsubscribe') - '["123456789"]'
WHERE primarykey = 'primarykey';
```

But this removes the entire object EXCEPT `["1232456789"]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work right here, adapt as needed!

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_jsonb_column=jsonb_set(your_jsonb_column,'{unsubscribe}',(your_jsonb_column->'unsubscribe')-'123456789') WHERE your_condition;
```